# How to remove href attribute from anchor tag after loading or while loading the page by using java script or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have to make link disable so that i tried to remove href attribute from a tag so that i used below code but the dom is not getting at the time it showing error. please help me to overcome the error.

```
var a = document.querySelector('.link');
a.removeattribute('href');
```

error shown: null of removeAttribute().

suggestion  in jquery also fine.

Comment: Put your script at the end of the body.

Comment: `removeAttribute` requires the name of the attribute as an argument. So `removeAttribute('href')` would work

Comment: @PhilipRollins sorry i have forget to put in question can u say some other solution.

Comment: If you have the `removeAttribute('href')` then the issue is the querySelector did not find any matches and returned null check `if (a !== null)`

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example of my comment.

```js
(() =>
{
  document.querySelectorAll('a')
    .forEach(a =>
    {
      a.addEventListener('click', () =>
      {
        a.removeAttribute('href');
      }, true);
    });
})();
```

```css
a:not([href])
{
  color: rgb(255, 80, 80);
}

a
{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#loading">Load that page</a>
<a href="#">Or that page</a>
<a href="#">Perhaps even that other page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript version:

```
var a = document.querySelector('.link');

a.removeAttribute('href');
```

jQuery version:

```
$('.link').removeAttr('href');
```

**Note:** `removeAttribute` is different from `removeattribute`, so when you decide to use js version, make sure you type the name correctly.